# Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400028. error code in Qtspim

Tags: mips, qtspim

I have to convert this C code to Mips and I run the code on Qtspim

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 1000; i++)
    sum = sum + i;
    printf("sum=%d", sum);

    return 0;

}
```

and my mips code is

```
#s1:i, t0:flag, s2:sum

    .data


    .text
    .globl main
main:

    li $s1, 0
    li $s2, 0
    Loop:
        slt $t0, $s1, 1000
        beq $t0, $0, Exit
        add $s2, $s2, $s1
        addi $s1, $s1, 1
        j Loop
    Exit:


    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $s2
    syscall
```

this code prints the right value but still causes the error message. please help me

Comment: As I commented on your previous question: _"You haven't added any code to terminate the program (e.g. system call 10)."_

Comment: Yes! I made it.

Comment: That was the answer thank you so much pal